# Outcome of BehaviorSpace

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating a classroom to find the total energy consumption from appliances of a classroom. Now I want to run the simulation in BehaviorSpace so that I get the energy consumption by varying the number of students in the classroom.

```
         globals[
        temp1 a s simulation-timer number-of-seats number-of-lights 
       number-of-fans number-of-acs gap row col x-cor y-cor half half2 
       student-no t-light t-fan t-ac t-energy
              ]
          breed [seats seat]
         breeed [seat-teachers seat-teacher]
         breed [lights light]
         breed [fans fan]
         breed [acs ac ]
         breed [students student ]

         to setup
         clear-all

          ask patches [ set pcolor 9 ]
          set gap floor ((max-pxcor) / (no-of-row-or-col) )
          set half ceiling (gap / 2)
          set half2 floor (gap / 2)
          place-seat-teachers
          place-seats-students
          place-lights
          place-fans
          place-acs
          ask patches with [ pxcor = 3 * gap + half2 ] [ set pcolor 4 ]
          ask patches with [ pxcor = 6 * gap + half2 ] [ set pcolor 4 ]
          create-students-classroom
          reset-ticks
          reset-timer
          end


          to go
          while [simulation-timer < time ] [

          move-students
          set simulation-timer simulation-timer + 1
          tick ]
           stop
            end

            to create-students-classroom                                    
            create-students number-of-students [
             set entry-time random threshold + 1                         ; 
              set random-entry time to each student

            let stu-no sort-on [who] students                          
            foreach stu-no [x -> ask x [ show (word x " -> " entry-time ) 
            ] ]  
            set shape "person"
            set color 3
               ]
           set s sort [who] of seats                                       
          set a first s

          end

           to move-students                                               

           let l length s

           set temp1 simulation-timer
           tick

          ask students [ if ( entry-time = temp1 )                   
              [
    move-to seat a                                          
   set color red
    appliance-on                                             
    show (word temp1 "," l "," a)
    set s remove a s
    set a a + 1
    set l length s
  ]
]
  end

   to appliance-on                                                    

     ask lights with [not l-on? and any? students in-radius 4]
     [ switch-light-on ]
      ask fans with [not f-on? and any? students in-radius 4]
      [ switch-fan-on]
        ask acs with [ not a-on? and any? students in-radius 9]
      [ switch-ac-on]

        stop

         end
         to switch-light-on                                             
         set color green
         set l-on? true
          set light-turned-on simulation-timer
         set light-on-duration light-on-duration + (time - light-turned-on 
          )
            type "light on duration " print light-on-duration
           end

            to-report energy-calculation

           ask lights [ ifelse ( l-on? )  [ set l-energy (light-on- 
            duration * light-wattage) ][ set l-energy 0 ] ]
             ask fans [ ifelse ( f-on? ) [ set f-energy ( fan-on-duration 
            * fan-wattage )] [ set f-energy 0 ] ]
            ask acs [ ifelse ( a-on? ) [ set a-energy (ac-on-duration * 
             ac-wattage) ] [ set a-energy 0 ] ]

             let light-e sum [l-energy] of lights
              let fan-e sum [f-energy] of fans
              let ac-e sum [a-energy] of acs

              set t-light ( light-e / (60000))
              set t-fan ( fan-e / (60000))
              set t-ac ( ac-e / ( 60000 ) )

              show (word "sum of ac energy = " ac-e )

               report ( t-light + t-fan + t-ac )

                  end
```

In the BehaviorSpace: measure runs using these reporters I am putting energy-calculation but in the spreadsheet everything is showing zero. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Abdullah,

I can't run your code as you've provided it, but I suspect that the problem lies in your `go` procedure. BehaviorSpace treats the `go` procedure as a forever button, that is it keeps running until either the number of ticks exceeds the `Time limit` or until it is stopped by some other user-supplied condition.  Moreover, BS runs the reporters listed under `Measure runs using these reporters` only at the end of each iteration of the `go` procedure. It assumes each iteration takes a tick. Your `go` procedure, however, only runs once.  The `while` loop is executed `time` times, but that is all within the first (and only) iteration of `go`, after which the simulation is stopped by the `stop` command.  I'm not sure why you are using `simulation-timer` instead of `ticks` to keep tract of the time, but let me suggest a `go` procedure that will do what I suspect you want.

```
to go    
  move-students
  tick 
  if ticks > time [ stop ]
end
```

In this case, `go` will keep going, and BS will report energy-calculation at the end of each iteration of `go`, until the number of iterations (ticks) exceeds `time`.  If you set `Time limit` in BS to `time`, the `if` statement will be redundant, but not if you are also running the model outside of BS. (If you are running from the interface tab, the `go` button should be a "forever" button.)

You also have a redundant `stop` at the end of your `appliance-on` procedure.

I may have missed something important in what you are trying to do, but perhaps this will get you started in solving your problem.

Comment: I am using simulation-timer because to move students, each student have a entry-time and when the simulation-timer equals that entry-time the student will enter. If I use ticks he program does not function properly.