# BehaviorSpace Output

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I am simulating a classroom to find the total energy consumption from appliances of a classroom. Now I want to run the simulation in BehaviorSpace so that I get the energy consumption (energy-calculation) by varying the number of students in the classroom.

```
                globals[
             temp1 simulation-timer number-of-seats number-of-lights 
    number-of-fans number-of-acs gap row col x-cor y-cor half half2 
  student-no t-light t-fan t-ac t-energy
       ]
      breed [seats seat]
     breed [seat-teachers seat-teacher]
     breed [lights light]
     breed [fans fan]
     breed [acs ac ]
     breed [students student ]


    seats-own [
    seat-color
     occupied?
       ]

    seat-teachers-own [
   seat-color

     ]

    students-own [
    entry-time
     found-seat
     ]

    lights-own [
    l-energy
     ]
    fans-own [
    f-energy
    ]
    acs-own [
      a-energy
      ]
       to setup
        clear-all

     ask patches [ set pcolor 9 ]
      set gap floor ((max-pxcor) / (no-of-row-or-col) )
     set half ceiling (gap / 2)
     set half2 floor (gap / 2)
     place-seat-teachers
     place-seats-students
     place-lights
     place-fans
     place-acs
     ask patches with [ pxcor = 3 * gap + half2 ] [ set pcolor 4 ]
     ask patches with [ pxcor = 6 * gap + half2 ] [ set pcolor 4 ]
     create-students-classroom
     reset-ticks
     reset-timer

     end

     to place-seat-teachers
     create-seat-teachers 1 [
     setxy ((max-pxcor - min-pxcor) / 2) 1
     set shape "square"
     set size 3
     set color red
     ]
     end


     to place-seats-students
     set row gap
     set col gap
     set x-cor 0
     set y-cor 0

    while [ x-cor <= gap * no-of-row  ]
    [
    ifelse (x-cor = row)[
   set col gap
    set y-cor 0
    while [ y-cor <= gap * no-of-row-or-col ]
  [
    ifelse (y-cor = col)[
      create-seats 1 [
        set shape "square"
        set size 1.5
        set color blue

        setxy col row
        set label who
        set number-of-seats number-of-seats + 1
        show (word row ", " col )

      ]
      set col col + gap
      set y-cor y-cor + 1
    ]
    [set y-cor y-cor + 1]
    ]
    set row row + gap
    set x-cor x-cor + 1
    ]
    [set x-cor x-cor + 1]
     ]
     end


      to place-lights
      set row gap + half2
      set col gap + half
      set x-cor 0
      set y-cor 0

       while [ x-cor <= gap * no-of-row-or-col ]
       [
       ifelse (x-cor = row)[
       set col gap + half
       set y-cor 0
       while [ y-cor <= gap * no-of-row ]
        [
       ifelse (y-cor = col)[
       create-lights 1 [
        set shape "pentagon"
        set size 1
        set color red

        setxy row col
        set number-of-lights number-of-lights + 1
        show (word row "," col )
      ]
      set col col + ( gap * 2)
       set y-cor y-cor + 1
        ]
        [set y-cor y-cor + 1]
        ]
        set row row + ( gap * 2)
        set x-cor x-cor + 1
         ]
         [set x-cor x-cor + 1]
         ]
         end

         to place-fans
         set row ( gap * 2 ) + half2
         set col gap + half
         set x-cor 0
         set y-cor 0

         while [ x-cor <= ( gap * no-of-row-or-col ) ]
         [
          ifelse (x-cor = row)[
          set col gap + half
           set y-cor 0
           while [ y-cor <= ( gap * no-of-row ) ]
            [
          ifelse (y-cor = col)[
        create-fans 1 [
        set shape "x" ;; x shape
        set size 1
        set color red

        setxy row col
        set number-of-fans number-of-fans + 1
        show (word row "," col )
      ]
      set col col + ( gap * 2)
       set y-cor y-cor + 1
       ]
        [set y-cor y-cor + 1]
         ]
         set row row + ( gap * 2)
         set x-cor x-cor + 1
          ]
          [set x-cor x-cor + 1]
            ]
          end

         to place-acs
         set row 3
         set col 13
         set x-cor 0
         set y-cor 0

          while [ y-cor <= 45 ]
             [
          ifelse (y-cor = col)[
          create-acs 1 [
         set shape "star" ;; star shape
         set size 1
         set color red

        setxy row col
        set number-of-acs number-of-acs + 1
        show (word row "," col )
          ]
        set col col + 10
         set y-cor y-cor + 1
         ]
         [set y-cor y-cor + 1]
           ]

         end
        to go
         set simulation-timer 0                              

         output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )    
         tick

          move-students
          while [simulation-timer < time ] [
         set simulation-timer simulation-timer + 1                       
         output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )
           ]
          end





            to create-students-classroom                                    
           create-students number-of-students [
            set entry-time random threshold + 1                         

             let stu-no sort-on [who] students                           
          foreach stu-no [x -> ask x [ show (word x " -> " entry-time ) ] 
          ]            
          set shape "person"
          set color 3
           ]
         end

         to move-students                                               
         let s sort [who] of seats
         let a first s
         let l length s
         while [ l > (number-of-seats - number-of-students )] [       
         set temp1 simulation-timer
          tick
           tick
            ask students [ if ( entry-time = temp1 )                   
            [
            move-to seat a                                          ; If it does the student moves to a seat
   set color red
    appliance-on
    energy-calculation
    show (word temp1 "," l "," a)
    set s remove a s
    set a a + 1
    set l length s

      ]
       ]
      set simulation-timer simulation-timer + 1                      
     output-show (word "timer = "simulation-timer )

      ]
       end

      to appliance-on
      ask students [ ask lights in-radius 4
      [ set color green ]]
        ask students [ ask fans in-radius 4
       [ set color green ]]
      ask students [ ask acs in-radius 9
        [ set color green ]]
        stop

         end

        to energy-calculation

         ask lights [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set l-energy ( light- 
         wattage * (time - temp1 )) ] [ set l-energy 0 ] ]
         ask fans [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set f-energy ( fan-wattage 
          * ( time - temp1 )) ] [ set f-energy 0 ] ]
          ask acs [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set a-energy (ac-wattage * 
          (time - temp1 ))] [ set a-energy 0 ] ]

           let light-e sum [l-energy] of lights
           let fan-e sum [f-energy] of fans
            let ac-e sum [a-energy] of acs

           set t-light ( light-e / 60 )
           set t-fan (fan-e / 60 )
           set t-ac (ac-e / 60 )
           show (word "total-ac-time = " t-ac )

            set t-energy ( t-light + t-fan + t-ac )

             end
```

In the BehaviorSpace: measure runs using these reporters I am putting energy-calculation but in the spreadsheet everything is showing zero. Why is this happening? When I am seeing the energy-calculation in a monitor it shows a value. What I want to do is run this code several times with different student numbers and get the varied energy-calculation each time. Or should I use file save in .csv for this situation?

Comment: Show us the code for the monitor. And show us what you have in the BehaviorSpace dialogue box. Please remove the very long model code you have provided, only keeping any bits that are relevant to making the monitor code work.

Comment: I see that you have not changed your `go` procedure since the last time you asked this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305898/outcome-of-behaviorspace/60311688#60311688 . I continue to think that this is contributing to your problem.

Comment: The screenshot of the netlogo interface is shared below for your convenience. The code is working but the BehaviourSpace is not.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wz0gV3gpbI75IDH0A-Bo6EJOKEX8ubM3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We need to see a screenshot of the BehaviorSpace experiment window and, if possible, an example of the output.

Comment: The screenshot of the behaviorspace experiment window is given below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/155JlSvvW0nwveYOsAbsJx6LLycy1CYuB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: experiment aborted due to syntax error. This is what I am getting.

Comment: Ah, then the answer I just posted does address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have written `energy-calculation` as a command that sets the global variable `t-energy` rather than as a reported that reports `t-energy` to the caller. I suspect that in your monitor you have used the `t-energy` variable which is reset each time `energy-calculation` is called.  But in BehaviorSpace, the reporter by which runs are measured must actually be a reporter.  It must return a value to BehaviorSpace.  This is easily done by rewriting `energy-calculation` as

```
to-report energy-calculation

  ask lights [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set l-energy ( light- 
    wattage * (time - temp1 )) ] [ set l-energy 0 ] ]
  ask fans [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set f-energy ( fan-wattage 
    * ( time - temp1 )) ] [ set f-energy 0 ] ]
  ask acs [ ifelse ( color = green ) [ set a-energy (ac-wattage * 
    (time - temp1 ))] [ set a-energy 0 ] ]

  let light-e sum [l-energy] of lights
  let fan-e sum [f-energy] of fans
  let ac-e sum [a-energy] of acs

  set t-light ( light-e / 60 )
  set t-fan (fan-e / 60 )
  set t-ac (ac-e / 60 )
  show (word "total-ac-time = " t-ac )

  set t-energy ( t-light + t-fan + t-ac )

  report t-energy

end
```

Whether or not you still need the global `t-energy` or can simply replace it with the reporter that reports its value, would depend on how else t-energy is used in the code.

But, I am actually surprised that the BehaviorSpace experiment tries to run at all.  BehaviorSpace should catch that `energy-calculation` is not a reporter and throw an error.